# Passing argumnets to one script.py file from another script.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want script1.py to loop a list and pass its output as an argument for another python file.

script1.py

```
list = ['1','2','3']

for x in list:
    subprocess.call("python3 script2.py", shell=True)
```

I want script2.py to use x as its input

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: From your call statement, you might want to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in script2.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the *script2.py* file is a file such as:

- script2.py

```py
import sys

argv = sys.argv
print(argv)
```

As you can see, this python file just shows the input argument. Note that the first argument always will be the file name.

Now suppose we want to loop over a list and pass the list elements to this script file as an argument. What we need to do simply is what follows:

- script1.py

```py
import subprocess
myList = ["arg_1", "arg_2", "arg_3"]
for x in myList:
  result = subprocess.run(["python", 'script2.py', x], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  print(result.stdout.decode("UTF-8").strip())
```

Note that *script1.py* and *script2.py* are in the same folder(directory).

##### Output

```
['script2.py', 'arg_1']
['script2.py', 'arg_2']
['script2.py', 'arg_3']
```